# "Wired" indoor/outdoor thermometer

Tags: voltage, dc, wire

Will doubling the original 9' length of (I think it is 28 gauge) low-voltage wire to the outdoor sensor affect thermometer performance? I've noticed that after some time, I get funky readings.

It works more reliably after I put in a new single AAA battery. The indoor reading is always fine. Is the signal too degraded after the battery wears down? I was thinking of hard wiring a transformer to the battery terminals.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a thermistor or especially a RTD , then yes, that much wire resistance will affect the measurement.

If it's a thermocouple then it will make the measurement more noisy.

If it's a digital sensor, then yes it will create issues because the wire will create a voltage drop whenever the sensor draws current. So this is the most likely situation. You might try higher gauge wire, but either way a voltage drop on the cables will happen and may degrade performance.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a precision thermistor sensor that is used as part of an RC oscillator circuit. The resulting frequency ratio between sensor and  a single inexpensive reference resistor yields the ratio in resistances- it is insensitive to supply voltage and capacitor value, so it’s ideal for low-cost battery-operated systems. 1% resistance tolerance represents only a few tenths of a degree C.

Unfortunately excessive capacitance in the cable can affect the operation. There’s not a lot you can do about that but reduce the capacitance per unit length of the cable or reduce the total length.